How to stop iPhone 13 Pro ringer / tone volume from automatically going to 100% when connect to car?
We have 2 iPhone 13 Pros doing the same thing - when we connect to the car via Bluetooth the iPhone ringer/tones volume automatically goes to 100%. When leaving the car it’s left at 100% so that the volume blasts when you get a call, etc.
What we’ve tried so far:
1 - reset volume settings by sliding the volume toggle to max the 0 five times as per Apple support.
2 - Restarting iPhone.
3-  Wiping and setting up as new.
4 - leaving on mute
5 - using a shortcut to lower volume when connected to car - does not always work
Does anyone know a way to stop the volume from going to 100% on its own?
Here is a short clip showing the volume action when iPhone is connecting to car.
volume increasing link
